# How to properly shape a search date sent to a NodeJS server with mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, next.js

In the app, I am developing I have a date `input` field.

I want to use it to search the `appointments` collection on a specific date.

On the server, I am dealing with all dates in `UTC` and this is how the search is going

```
  const date = // date in iso sent from client
  const startDate = new Date(date);
  const endDate = new Date(date);
  startDate.setUTCHours(0);
  endDate.setUTCHours(24);
  query.date = {
    $gte: startDate,
    $lt: endDate,
  };
```

The problem is whenever I search for a date from an `input` field some quirks are happening like

When I send to the date in `ISO` some searches from one day before will appear depending on the hours of that appointment.

I tried to change the date like this `date.setHours(0)` then send the `ISO` string, the same thing happens only difference the problem shows up when the hour of the appointment is over 5 AM in `UTC`

what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by switching `setUTCHours` to `setHours` on the server

the problem was that I was changing the hour of the `UTC` hour from the original date I have received which is making it fall behind for the offset difference so I am messing up the search dates so setting the locale hours gives the correct effect of searching between two dates and then mongoose already correctly searches the collection for desired dates.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is happening because of the time offset.
You can try adding the time offset difference to the UTC time. This might give you the desired result.

You can try something like this once you receive your date in ISO format.

19800 is the default value for TimeZone Offset in seconds for "Asia/Kolkata"

```
const newDate = new Date()
const serverOffset = newDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60
const utcDifference = 19800 + serverOffset
console.log(utcDifference);
```

You can use this UTCDifference to get your local time.